# Jquery - Counting JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im building a chart system that will show me all data entries. I retrieve my data using ajax and I loop trough the data and group the results by colors (red, blue and yellow) and then divide them by months.

I setup base objects (dateCounts_Red, dateCounts_Blue and dateCounts_Yellow) so that by default it starts all months at 0. A counter would then add when it finds a match tot he apropriate color and month.

When I output my dateCounts I get:

```
{"2015":{"2015-12":1,"2015-10":null,"2015-08":null,"2015-11":null}}
{"2015":{"2015-12":0,"2015-10":null}}
{"2015":{"2015-12":0,"2015-10":null}}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var dateCounts_Red = {"2015":{"2015-01":0,"2015-02":0,"2015-03":0,"2015-04":0},"2015":{"2015-05":0},"2015":{"2015-06":0},"2015":{"2015-07":0},"2015":{"2015-08":0},"2015":{"2015-09":0},"2015":{"2015-10":0},"2015":{"2015-11":0},"2015":{"2015-12":0}};
var dateCounts_Blue = {"2015":{"2015-01":0,"2015-02":0,"2015-03":0,"2015-04":0},"2015":{"2015-05":0},"2015":{"2015-06":0},"2015":{"2015-07":0},"2015":{"2015-08":0},"2015":{"2015-09":0},"2015":{"2015-10":0},"2015":{"2015-11":0},"2015":{"2015-12":0}};
var dateCounts_Yellow = {"2015":{"2015-01":0,"2015-02":0,"2015-03":0,"2015-04":0},"2015":{"2015-05":0},"2015":{"2015-06":0},"2015":{"2015-07":0},"2015":{"2015-08":0},"2015":{"2015-09":0},"2015":{"2015-10":0},"2015":{"2015-11":0},"2015":{"2015-12":0}};

data.d.results.forEach(function(element) {
  var date = element.created_date.slice(0, 7);
  var yr = date.slice(0, 4);
  var Color = element.colorvalue;

  if(Color == "red") {
  dateCounts_Red[yr][date]++;
  }

  if(Color == "blue"){
  dateCounts_Blue[yr][date]++;
  }

  if(Color == "yellow"){
  dateCounts_Yellow[yr][date]++;
  }

});

Red_yr_2015_data = [dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-01'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-02'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-03'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-04'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-05'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-06'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-07'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-08'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-09'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-10'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-11'], dateCounts_Red['2015']['2015-12']];
Blue_yr_2015_data = [dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-01'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-02'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-03'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-04'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-05'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-06'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-07'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-08'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-09'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-10'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-11'], dateCounts_Blue['2015']['2015-12']];
Yellow_yr_2015_data = [dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-01'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-02'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-03'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-04'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-05'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-06'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-07'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-08'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-09'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-10'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-11'], dateCounts_Yellow['2015']['2015-12']];
```

Im currently getting the following error from my Highcharts js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined
```

THis is preventing the chart system to work correctly the data returned is not being returned with it's expected data.

Here a full example to the issue https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/21/

Would anyone know what im missing?

Comment: Um, so what is the problem?

Comment: First of all `url: basePath = 'Incidents?$orderby=created_date',` in your `$.mockjax()` Object is not proper Object notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date count objects have major structural flaw.

When you prettify them they look like:

```
var dateCounts_Blue = {
      "2015": {
        "2015-01": 0,
        "2015-02": 0,
        "2015-03": 0,
        "2015-04": 0
      },
      "2015": {
        "2015-05": 0
      },
      "2015": {
        "2015-06": 0
      },
      "2015": {
        "2015-07": 0
      },
       ......
```

Object keys must be unique so these are clearly being repeated and the compiler will over write duplicates.

Fix the pattern that breaks away from the intended pattern grouping at the beginning

Comment: Agree to this. OP needs to simply remove the unnecessary repeating `"2015"` keys, so the json would look like: `{"2015":{"2015-01":0,"2015-02":0,"2015-03":0,"2015-04":0, "2015-05":0, "2015-06":0, "2015-07":0, "2015-08":0, "2015-09":0, "2015-10":0, "2015-11":0, "2015-12":0}}`. As can be seen in this fiddle, it will then work (I left only reds there) - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/awo5aaqb/22/

Comment: Yeah that worked, small oversight when I copied and pasted. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateCounts_Red = {
"2015":
{
"2015-01":0,
"2015-02":0,
"2015-03":0,
"2015-04":0,
"2015-05":0,
"2015-06":0,
"2015-07":0,
"2015-08":0,
"2015-09":0,
"2015-10":0,
"2015-11":0,
"2015-12":0
},
};
var dateCounts_Blue = {
"2015":{
"2015-01":0,
"2015-02":0,
"2015-03":0,
"2015-04":0,
"2015-05":0,
"2015-06":0,
"2015-07":0,
"2015-08":0,
"2015-09":0,
"2015-10":0, 
"2015-11":0,
"2015-12":0
}
};
var dateCounts_Yellow = {
"2015":{
"2015-01":0,
"2015-02":0,
"2015-03":0,
"2015-04":0,
"2015-05":0,
"2015-06":0,
"2015-07":0,
"2015-08":0,
"2015-09":0,
"2015-10":0,
"2015-11":0,
"2015-12":0}
};
```

Your data structure is flawed and such comparing values when doing the foreach loop becomes inconsistent because it compares it to multiple values, the above JSON is the fix for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite codereview.stackexchange.com, but I heavily modified your javascript to make it work a bit better

```
$.ajax({
  url: basePath,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {

    var counts = {};

    data.d.results.forEach(function(element) {
      // If you know it's all the same year, you could totally ignore this
      var yr = element.created_date.slice(0, 4);
      var month = parseInt(element.created_date.slice(5,7));
      var color = element.colorvalue;

      if (counts[color] === undefined) {
        counts[color] = {};
      }
      if (counts[color][yr] === undefined) {
        counts[color][yr] = {};
      }

      current_value = counts[color][yr][month];
      if (current_value === undefined) {
        // Doesnt exist yet, so add it
        counts[color][yr][month] = 1;
      } else {
        // Exists, so increment by 1
        counts[color][yr][month] = current_value + 1;
      }
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(counts));
    console.log(transform_series(counts['red']['2015']));
    console.log(transform_series(counts['blue']['2015']));
    console.log(transform_series(counts['yellow']['2015']));

    var Options = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'myfirstchart',
        type: 'column',
        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
          enabled: true,
          alpha: 25,
          beta: 0,
          depth: 70
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: "Test Highcharts"
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Test charts'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          depth: 25
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"]
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Number of entries"
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y} / {point.stackTotal}'
      },

      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          depth: 40
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Red',
        color: 'red',
        data: transform_series(counts['red']['2015']),
        stack: '2015'
      }, {
        name: 'Blue',
        color: 'blue',
        data: transform_series(counts['blue']['2015']),
        stack: '2015'
      }, {
        name: 'Yellow',
        color: 'yellow',
        data: transform_series(counts['yellow']['2015']),
        stack: '2015'
      }]

    };

    return new Highcharts.Chart(Options);

  }
});


// this transforms the hash {10: 5, 11:1, 12:1} to get you all 12 months
// and returns an array of values [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... 5, 1, 1] that
// can be used in high charts
function transform_series(series) {
        return Array.apply(null, Array(13)).map(function (_, i) {return (series[i] === undefined) ? 0 : series[i];}).slice(1,13);
}
```

Comment: HI Prescot, is it normal that it's only populating the 3 lasts months and not all 12 months?

Comment: It should populate it all, but the mock data only seems to have 10, 11 and 12 months

Comment: I modified the mockdata, what i figured out is that it's not recognizing months with zeroes in them (01,02,03,04,05,06,08,09). Other numbers are fine (10,11,12). Trying to figure out why it would do this.

Comment: If you get a chance heres the modified code https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/27/. If you look at the console the counts are being captured properly but when passing them trough the transform_series function, all the counts before the month of October are returning 0.

Comment: @DanielEllison Well figured out, the month should be parsed as an integer: `var month = parseInt(element.created_date.slice(5,7));` Updated https://jsfiddle.net/awo5aaqb/28/